# Is it possible to buy high pass filters that work in the 100 kHz range?

Tags: filter, multiplier

I want a device that rejects 100 kHz but lets through 150 kHz. I tried building a simple passive first order circuit but the roll-off wasn't sharp enough. Most standard electronics vendors don't seem to sell anything below 1 Mhz.

Alternatively, I could also use a frequency tripler that accepts input at 50 kHz - again most vendors didn't seem to have any that worked below 1 Mhz.

Comment: What's the band of the signal you're interested in?  (The lower limit is at 150khz.  What's the upper limit?)

Comment: there isn't really an upper limit - the signal I'm looking for should be very close to 150 kHz

Comment: The reason why I was asking about the upper bound of the frequency is that a practical filter will [inevitably] have a roll off at a high frequency.  This happens because of parasitics or because of max GBW in OpAmps.

Comment: oh - I guess for my application any roll off over ~200 kHz or so should be fine

Comment: "rejects" and "lets through" are useless specs.  No filter will reject everything in the stop band and not attenuate anything in the pass band.  How much loss is acceptable at 150 kHz?  How much attenuation is good enough at 100 kHz?  What is the real passband range?  How much can gain vary over this passband?

Comment: Use this [software tool](http://www.ti.com/tool/filterpro) from Texas Instruments to desgin higher order active filters.

Comment: thanks - I'll check the tool out. I should've been clearer, I'm hoping for an attenuation of over 30dB at 100kHz and a loss of not more than a few percent at 150 kHz.

Comment: Synchronous detect the 150 kHz signal. The 100 & 200 kHz will be 50 kHz away, and out of audio amplifier band.

Comment: @Nick - not necessarily true for a passive filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a parallel LC tuned circuit in series with your input. Theoretically it has infinite impedance and if tuned correctly it should dramatically reduce signals at 100kHz. Follow this with a series tuned circuit at 150kHz to further enhance your signal with respect to all other sources of noise or interference: -

[image]

Here's one I quickly put thru the simulator. Notice that at 100kHz there is almost 50dB rejection whilst at, and around, 150kHz the attenuation is about 14 milli dB.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by a parallel LC tuned circuit - is that the same as a passive filter?

Comment: @mhp, the volunteers here that answer questions are by and large electrical and electronic engineers.  When answering a question, these volunteers assume that there is, at least, a common language to communicate an answer in.  When you write "I'm not sure I understand what you mean by parallel LC tuned circuit", it's not far from writing "I'm not sure what you mean byrepeated addition" over at math.SE.

Comment: @Andy aka Which software did you use to simulate the filter?

Comment: @AndrejaKo I use micro-cap 9

Comment: thanks everyone - I'm from a physics background and have close to zero experience with electronics, which might explain my naiveté